# Is it necessarily true that if we have an open set in $T \times S$ that it must be the product of two open sets?

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking $(0,1) \times [0,1]$ but I no longer think that is open in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right that this set is not open in $\mathbb R^2$. You may want to prove this easy fact as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $(0,1) \times (1,2) \cup (1,2) \times (0,1)$. This set is open in $\mathbb R^2$ but not the product of two open sets.

It is, however, the union of products of open sets and this is in fact always true for the product topology. (That is to say the product topology is the coarsest topology containing all products of open sets in the respective factor spaces.)

Comment: Further example. The set of all points in the plane less than one unit from the line $y=x$ is open. To get that you need the union of infinitely many products of open sets.

Comment: Or the interior of a circle as well.